# user postgres cannot access drive even after permissions and group membership are provided

Tags: 14.04, permissions, users, postgresql

I have been working on this for the better part of the morning. So I upgraded to ubuntu 14.04 last night, and that went smoothly. But there is an issue with the postgres user and access to my postgresql database data directory.

So the database folder is on a separate harddrive. When I mount the drive, the system mounts it to the /media/krishnab/{drive} folder as per the current `udisks2` standard. So now the postgres user has to go through my `home` directory in order to get to the database folder.

I have included the postgres user in my `krishnab` group and also given the account a linux password. My home folder has "Me" (krishnab) as the owner and group `krishnab`. I have rebooted the pc a number of times too. However, whenever the postgres user tries to access the `/media/krishnab` folder there is always a `permission denied` error. I have also checked my `/home/krishnab/` folder permissions to make sure they are good--`krishnab` is the group--and they are fine. I checked the permissions on the folder too and they are `drwxrwxr-x+`. So still no luck.

The only thing I noticed was that when I use the gnome-system-tools, I do not see the `postgres` user as a member of the `krishnab` group, but when I do `sudo cat /etc/group` I find that the only member of the krishnab group is `krishnab:x:1000:postgres`. So I am wondering why myself `krishnab` is no a member of my own group `krishnab`.

Any suggestions? I can't seem to figure out what I am missing.
Thanks.

Comment: Ahh figured it out. Somehow there was an access control list on the folder `/media/krishnab/`, so I was able to just use the `setfacl -m u:postgres:rwx /media/krishnab` and that fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahh figured it out. Somehow there was an access control list on the folder `/media/krishnab/`, so I was able to just use the `setfacl -m u:postgres:rwx /media/krishnab` and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

By any chance did you try to re-apply the permissions to /media/krishnab i.e. chmod -R /media/krsihnab? Wondering if the uid or gids are no longer the same.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man8/adduser.8.html

Mike